# Dependencies in UML State Diagram

Tags: uml

I basically have a class like the following:

```
class Stack {
  ...
  push()
  pop()
  isEmpty()
  ...

  class StackIterator extends Iterator {
    ...
    hasNext()
    next()
    ...
  }
}
```

and I want to create a UML state diagram for the iterator. My idea was to use a dependency arrow and Stack calls to model the Iterator states as follows:

[image]

Would this be a valid, industrial proof and fully understandable UML state diagram for situations like this?

Comment: What your SM misses most is a Start.

Comment: @qwerty_so Yes, of course. This is just a small "pseudo" state diagram to show the basic idea behind my question. The start would be in the Stack SM and one going to the "empty" state in the StackIterator for example. Same for finite states.

Comment: Even (or especially) in small examples you should stick to basic rules. Anyway, see my answer...

Answer (score 0):

A state machine can be the behavior of an operation, but to associate a state machine to a class is very strange and out of UML because a class does not have a behavior.

A dependency between state machine has no predefined meaning in UML. You want to indicate the inheritance between your classes but while a state machine does not have to be associated to a class that dependency is not relevant

[edit]

For people having a doubt about the fact a state machine can be the behavior of an operation, I encourage you to look at the norm :

- StateMachine inherits Behavior (§14.2.2 of formal 2017-12-5)
- Operation inherits BehavioralFeature (§ 9.6.2)
- a BehavioralFeature is implemented (realized) by a Behavior (§ 9.9.2))

Note the behavior of an operation can also be supported my an Activity being also a Behavior

Comment: *A state machine can be the behavior of an operation* - not quite, a transition between state can be the behavior of an operation. State machine depicts the states and all the transitions between them.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I disagree, I encourage you to look at the norm, StateMachine inherits Behavior (§14.2.2 of formal 2017-12-5), Operation inherits BehavioralFeature (§ 9.6.2) and a  BehavioralFeature is implemented (realized) by a Behavior (§ 9.9.2)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're talking about modeling of state machine in terms of class diagram. I (and the OP as it seems) are referencing state machines in scope of UML State diagram.

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername "*you're talking about modeling of state machine in terms of class diagram*" not at all, I think you do not understand the meta model of UML, I encourage you to refer to the norm at least in the chapters I indicated. "*referencing state machines in scope of UML State diagram*" this is not because a state machine is represented through a state diagram that a state machine cannot be associated to an operation or any other element which is not shown in a state diagram

Comment: @bruno I more or less only included the Stack "pseudo"-class above so that people know what I am talking about. The transitions in the state diagram below (i.e. "Stack#pop" and "Stack#push") are in no relation to a class diagram or the pseudo-class above. The state diagram should only model things like "if an element was pushed to the stack, this also updates the state of the iterator". As said, completely decoupled from any class diagrams etc. Would it be a valid UML state diagram in this case? Thank you!

Comment: Let's not deviate. The OP is not asking about meta model, he is asking about state diagram, which is simply a formalized UML way to depict state machines.

Comment: @null1 sorry for the joke but if all you show is pseudo-something what to say except this is pseudo-valid  :-) Your state machine is named like your class and all inside exists in your class, how to not make a link. After for your precise question about the dependency I already answer *a dependency between state machine has no predefined meaning in UML*, so this is not invalid but you have to explain its meaning

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername I do not understand your remark, that meta model defines UML, it indicates how to understand / use UML, all you do in UML is directed by the definition of UML, else what are we speaking about ? Where is the quiproquo ?

Comment: @bruno Ahh, i see, thank you very much! I got this dependency relation from another stackoverflow post, I didn't know that it was invalid in UML (or better say undefined). But how would you model states like the ones in the "StackIterator" where the transition completely depends on something outside its own context then? Just add a custom definition what the "dependency" means?

Comment: @bruno We're talking about using UML to define state machine.

Comment: @null1 you do not have to show that specifically through an artifice, I mean this is part or your signals/guard/... , like when a transition is associated to an external signal where you just indicate the signal. A given diagram does not have to show all, and it cannot, this is why there are several kind of diagrams. After if you *really* want to show that in your diagram you can add a note, but ask yourself if there is a real plus value to do ;-)

Comment: @bruno Alright, notes sound great, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the behavior of the stack you should simply use an activity diagram. The filled/empty states are superfluous and you get the guard for the pop with the `[size >=1 ]` condition easily.

Btw. nothing is endless. The push should have a `[size < max]` or the like.

Comment: But the max parameter would indicate that there is a fixed upper limit for my Stack and I would need a "full" state. After all this is not true for the Iterator. Even more there should not be any upper bound for either of them. Both are dynamically growing. But would you still recommend adding a "max" value?

Comment: Well, this is a pure technical/practical aspect. You well can let run your app into a memory overflow. I would judge that just a bad design.